# Geocoder simply don't geocode

Tags: node.js, geolocation

[image: the return]

I'm trying to geocode a address for hours but the geocoder simply don't geocode, here is my code:

```
const nodegeocoder = require('node-geocoder')

const options = {
    provider: 'openstreetmap'
}
const geocoder = nodegeocoder(options)
```

A scheme goes here

```
UserScheme.pre('save', async function(next) {
     //geocoding
     const geocode = await geocoder.geocode(this.address)
     console.log(geocode)
})
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: it simply dont geocode, instead it return a null